# React - How to apply styles via ref

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, jsx, ref

I have a reference for a container and I want to change his background-position. 
That needs to happen inside of a function and the values are dynamic, so I can't create a class for that.

```
slideRef.current.style["background-position-x"] = "-262.5px"
setTimeout(function(){
  slideRef.current.classList.add("spin_animation");
  slideRef.current.style = {backgroundPositionX: "-" + scrollAmount + "px"}
 10);
```

I tried two ways, accessing a property and not using a camel case and the other one was passing the style as an object like an inline style.

How can I apply the background-position, accessing directly the ref?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
elementRef.current.style.backgroundPositionX = "-262.5px";
```

```js
const App = () => {
  const elementRef = React.useRef(null);
  const handler = () => {
    if (elementRef.current) {
      elementRef.current.style.color = "red";
      elementRef.current.style.backgroundPositionX = "-262.5px";
      console.log(elementRef.current.style);
    }
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1 ref={elementRef}>Sample Text</h1>
      <h2 onClick={handler}>Click me to change the style of the text</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.12.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.12.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hello! How could you do this same with class component? I tried something like this.searchField Ref.current.style.background = "#f60909"; but it tells me that it is undefined